# can we Include naming convention in the Link Tooltip field for each link- for tracking the click behavior of a particular image

Tags: marketing-cloud

can we Include naming convention in the Link Tooltip field for each link- for tracking the click behavior of a particular image .

what are the different methods would ensure click behaviour on these images if tracked with the naming convention

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the `alias` attribute.

> `<a href="http://salesforce.com" alias="Salesforce Link" conversion="true">Salesforce</a>`
>   Link attributes such as alias
>   and conversion are used to control how Marketing Cloud wraps the
>   links. They are removed so they are not present in the message
>   received.

By setting an alias, you are able to differentiate each link, even if they are to the same destination.

This 'link name' (via alias attribute) is used to set the name inside of the Email tracking, as well as 'LinkName' in the _Click Data View.

You can even make this dynamic via profile attributes, data extension fields or AMPscript variables.

`< a href="..." alias="%%=AttributeValue("LinkName1")=%%">...</a>`
Where LinkName1 is a data extension field or profile attribute with the name of the link you are using.

As each link would be named differently, they should now appear as separate links.